# How to fix Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'?

Tags: swift, search, realm, rx-swift, reactiveui

How to fix this problem `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'` , I spent 2 days looking for the solution for this problem. I hope someone could help me. I tried to debug and trace it and I found out it successfully enter to `.subscribe(onNext:)` and read `controller?.tableView.reloadData()` but If I continue program execution it will just terminate and error display in the console log.

```
        searchBar
            .rx.text
            .orEmpty
            .debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            .map({ [weak controller = self] query -> (tcb: [TrialCourtBranches], query: String)? in
                switch controller?.tcbArray {
                case .some(let array):
                    return (array, query)
                case .none:
                    return nil
                }
            })
            .observeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .userInitiated)) // change thread before filtering
            .map({ (query) -> [TrialCourtBranches] in // filter and return the result of filtering
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
                let tcb_safe = ThreadSafeReference(to: tcb)
                let filtered = realm.resolve(tcb_safe)
                let tcb_filtered:[TrialCourtBranches] = (filtered?.filter({ $0.branch_name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }))!
                return tcb_filtered
            })
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // go back to main thread
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak controller = self] (filtered) in
                tcb_filteredArray = filtered
                controller?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note I'm not really an IOS dev so this code could easily end up syntactically incorrect, but the issue is that this just isn't a good way to filter in Realm.

You could for example use RxRealm from https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm which allows you to expose Results as a Changeset Observable.

Then you can switchMap (or in your language, flatMapLatest) on it.

So the end result would be something like this

```
extension UITableView {
  func applyChangeset(_ changes: RealmChangeset) {
    beginUpdates()
    deleteRows(at: changes.deleted.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .automatic)
    insertRows(at: changes.inserted.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .automatic)
    reloadRows(at: changes.updated.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }, with: .automatic)
    endUpdates()
  }
}
```

And

```
    searchBar
        .rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .debounce(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        .map({ [weak controller = self] query -> (tcb: [TrialCourtBranches], query: String)? in
            switch controller?.tcbArray {
            case .some(let array):
                return (array, query)
            case .none:
                return nil
            }
        })
        .flatMapLatest({ (query) -> [TrialCourtBranches] in // filter and return the result of filtering
             let realm = try! Realm()
             let results = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
                      .filtered($0.branch_name.lowercased()
                      .contains(searchText.lowercased())) 
             return Observable.changeset(from: results)
        })
        .subscribe(onNext: {[unowned self] results, changes in
            if let changes = changes {
                controller?.tableView.applyChangeset(changes)
            } else {
                controller?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Output**

```
searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (data) in
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(branch_name CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (office_no CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.city_municipality CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.province CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.address1 CONTAINS[c] %@)",data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased())
                tcb_filteredArray = tcb.filter(predicate)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }, onError: { (errorResult) in
                print(errorResult)
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("onCompleted")
            }, onDisposed: {
                print("onDisposed")
            })
        .disposed(by: bag)
```